# Restored Gitlab to Local Server, it now always redirects to original server

Tags: nginx, backup, backup-restoration, gitlab

I restored a gitlab backup to my local computer just to see if i could make it work with another ldap server. Installed the same gitlab omnibus version to my machine, changed external url in gitlab.rb and restored the backup. Everything went smoothly but now whenever i try to hit my local gitlab it redirects to our original gitlab machine.

I've stopped nginx by gitlab-ctl, purged nginx and apache2 completely, even deleted the nginx folder inside /var/opt/gitlab/ but nothing works. I could go to the gitlab in machine with http://localhost:8080/users/sign_in but css files and javascripts don't load.

I don't know what else to do. UFW disabled, IPTables are flushed. There are not even a trace of any reverse proxy/web server application in my machine.

What can i do to debug this problem?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems that if a url is defined for redirecting non logged in users in the original gitlab interface, the config persists and it tries to take you to old url.

What needs to be done is log in to new gitlab instance with admin or someone with admin permissions and set the url to the new gitlab instance url/ip.

I'm going to mark this question as answered, maybe it helps another person.